# Meta Workplace API Inline Image Response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I have a post in Meta Workplace that looks as follows:

[image]

The picture of the Avocado was added by dragging the file into the message composer. The post looks fine when viewed in the browser.

When accessing the same post via the API it is completely missing any reference to the image:

```
{
            "message": "# inline image",
            "updated_time": "2023-04-13T14:56:57+0000",
            "created_time": "2023-04-13T14:56:57+0000",
            "from": {
                "name": "Gandalf",
                "id": "12345"
            },
            "formatting": "MARKDOWN",
            "type": "status",
            "to": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "12345",
                        "name": "Test Account"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": "12345_67890"
        }
```

I have the following fields set on my query `attachments,message,updated_time,created_time,from,formatting,icon,link,picture,poll,properties,status_type,type,to,story,tags`.

I am missing something or are inline images not returned by the API?

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Facing the same problem... Images are not referenced in the output whatsoever

Comment: @tarjeieo unfortunately not. We just accepted that it was a limitation in the API and directed users to add images in alternative ways 